# PHP Doc Blocker for Visual Studio Code not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make this extension to work on Visual Studio Code:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neilbrayfield.php-docblocker

When i call this extension to comment a PHP function it outputs this comment:

```php
/**
 * Undocumented function
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function simulations()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Simulation::class);
}
```

Instead of:

```php
/**
 * Undocumented function
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function simulations()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Simulation::class);
}
```

Here is my `Visual Studio Code` settings of PHP Doc Block:

```js
"php-docblocker.functionTemplate": {
  "message": {},
  "param": {},
  "return": {},
  "extra": {}
},
```

It just doesn't work, the only other extension i have on my VSCode is Intelephense.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

you have to make it explicit, what the function should return.

```
public function simulations(): HasMany
{
  return $this->hasMany(Simulation::class);
}
```